# Algorithm to connect all points in a shape

Tags: javascript, connection, polygon, point

I'm trying to figure out how to connect all points in a shape, with the amount of points being dynamic.

I'll use a square to demonstrate, there's four points:

a - top left,
b - top right,
c - bottom right,
d - bottom left

So...

```
var connections = [
    new Connection(a, b),
    new Connection(a, c),
    new Connection(a, d),
    new Connection(b, c),
    new Connection(b, d),
    new Connection(c, d)
];
```

Connects all points in a square (or any four sided polygon), but I want to do this automatically by looping through an array of points (displayed as abcd here for simplicity's sake) so it will work for any polygon. I tried to work out a pattern and implement it in a couple of for-loops but that failed. I expect it's really simple...

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Only an outline or a web?

Comment: If this is a 'square' as you describe it, then a connection between A (top left) and B (bottom right) makes no sense. Can you be more specific about what a 'polygon' is here, and what a Connection is here?

Comment: @JakeHeidt Any shape with 3 or more straight edges. Why does a connection between the top left and bottom right (which was C) make no sense? The connection is just a theoretical object.

Comment: Updated my answer with a working demo. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pseudocode:

```
for (var i=0; i<Shape.Count; i++) {
  for (var j=i+1; j<Shape.Count; j++) {
    List.Add(i,j);
  }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, this seems to work perfectly. Except `if(i != j)` needs to be added before `List.Add()` to avoid a point connecting to itself. I knew it would simple!

Comment: Ha! of course. It's even simpler than that of course - see amended code above.

Answer (score 2):

```
var Connection = function (a, b) {
    console.log('Connecting ' + a + ' and ' + b);
}

var points = ['a','b','c','d','e'];

(function traverse() {
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i += 1) {
        new Connection(points[0], points[ i + 1 ]);
    }
    points = points.slice(1);
    if (points.length > 1) {
        traverse(points);
    }
}());
```

That will output:

```
Connecting a and b
Connecting a and c
Connecting a and d
Connecting a and e
Connecting b and c
Connecting b and d
Connecting b and e
Connecting c and d
Connecting c and e
Connecting d and e
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1j5n5x55/